# How can I accurately determine application pool memory usage by an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis-7, application-pool

My hosting company imposes a 100mb memory limit on application pools (IIS 7.5).

How can I accurately determine the memory usage of my ASP.NET application?

In order to create some kind of base line I created an empty ASP.NET MVC 3 application with a single controller action, returning a string result.

Profiling this application with ANTS had the following results:

```
Generation 1 - 286.2KB
Generation 2 - 795.4KB
Large Object Heap - 75.63KB
Unused memory allocated to .NET - 1.323MB
Unmanaged - 26.78MB
```

My concern is that if the application pool restrictions is based on private bytes, then a blank ASP.NET MVC application is using 33MB of the pool's resource. Therefore my MVC application that actually does something (using 93MB) will easily go over the "limit".

If however, I call `GC.GetTotalMemory` then the result is 8MB, which sounds much more acceptable.

I've had absolutely no success in finding any benchmarks to test against, but if an empty MVC web application does indeed use 33MB of resource (this does sound excessive) then the restrictions that my host imposes seem completely unrealistic.

Many thanks,
Ben

Comment: 100MB does sound compeltely unrealistic.  One host I work with has a default under IIS 7.5 of 600MB, raisable to 800MB on request for shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Chat with your hosting provider to see whether that memory limit is for private memory or virtual limit.
2. Learn about private memory and virtual memory, and then make use of ANTS profiler to better understand your application's memory foot print.